# Remove the Browser ballot app from Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-8

I made the mistake of installing the browser choice app/update on one of my PCs and now, it cannot be uninstalled. I cannot uninstall the update and I can't even uninstall the "Metro" app it installs.

I have found this tutorial for Windows 7 online but I haven't found any feedback to tell if it really works:

> To uninstall KB 976002:
>
> 1. Go to C:\Windows\Servicing\Packages
> 2. Find the two .mum files relating to KB 976002
> 3. Take ownership of them, give yourself full control
> 4. Open Control Panel, programs, Installed Updates
> 5. Find KB 976002 and right click, Uninstall is not available. Important: Do not close this window, to avoid re-verification of the
>      checksum of the .mum files.
> 6. Go back to the two .mum files for 976002. Edit them both with notepad, change Permanance=”Permanent” to Permanence=”Removable”
> 7. Go back to the Installed updates list, hit F5, right click KB 976002. Uninstall is now available.
> 8. Uninstall the update (if you want to be double-careful, monitor with sysinternals process monitor).
> 9. Reinstate the two keys which the uninstall removes [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRunOnce]
>      [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRunOnceEx]
> 10. Reboot the PC
> 11. Run the 947821 update to verify the component store
> 12. Go to WU, check for updates, hide the 976002 update

Also I cannot find any related .mum files.

Does anybody know which mum files I should edit, if this method makes sense. Or does anybody have an alternative way of removing the update?

Answer (score 0):

Mum files will have KBxxxxxx in the file name, (xxxxxx represents the number of the update you wish to uninstall)

Instructions look sound, make a manual Windows restore point just before you perform the changes, that way you can revert them if it does not work, you make a mistake or causes issues.

Or you could see if you have a recent Windows restore point and restore the PC, it may revert the changes that KB update made.

Comment: Thanks, got it uninstalled but it did not remove the "Metro" App :(. Must be some other trick specifically for windows 8.