# browser choice: how to safely delete it?

Tags: windows, browser

Windows 8.1

I use another browser and in any case browser choice can never be useful for me.
I want to delete it from my PC, including the registry.

Apparently it is launched by the process WWAhost.exe, which I cannot disable as this process launches other apps also.

How can I safely delete browser choice files without risking having problems in the future when I update Windows 8.1 or other problems?

Pls note that my OS version does not have group policy.

I thank you in advance

Comment: Try IOBit Uninstaller.

Answer (score 1):

## Disable the Browser Choice application

All the Browser Choice files are stored in the following folder:

```
C:\Windows\BrowserChoice
```

The ballot screen executable is called `browserchoice.exe`. The update also adds a `BrowserChoice` entry in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Once installed, the Browser Choice update ([KB976002](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976002/en-gb)) can't be easily removed because it's designed to be permanent. While you could [modify some system files](https://superuser.com/questions/472446/remove-the-browser-ballot-app-from-windows-8) to work around this limitation, the update might be offered again in the future, and you would be back to square one. Manually deleting the related files is not recommended either for the same reason.

[Hiding the update](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/24376-windows-update-hide-restore-hidden-updates.html) before it gets installed it's a good idea, but you can otherwise prevent Browser Choice from running by following the steps below.

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8).
2. Type or paste the following commands:

   ```
   reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v "BrowserChoice" /f
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\BrowserChoice" /v "Enable" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\browserchoice.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "systray.exe" /f
   ```

### Additional information

> The Browser Choice update is a software update for Windows that Microsoft is required to distribute in Europe as part of legal Commitments to the European Commission.   The Browser Choice update is designed to inform customers who currently have Internet Explorer set as the default browser on their computers of the other web browsers available to them.  The Browser Choice Screen provides consumers with an easy way to see what other web browsers are available, to learn about those browsers and to install them if they choose to do so.
>
> #### Who will get the Browser Choice update?
>
> Users who have their regional settings set to one of the following countries or regions will get the Browser Choice update:
>
> Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, United Kingdom, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland.
>
> #### What does the Browser Choice Update do?
>
> After downloading the update and restarting your computer, if you have Internet Explorer set as your default browser, you'll automatically be shown the Browser Choice screen, and you can then select and install the browsers you want to use. You can also double-click the Browser Choice shortcut on the desktop to select and install the web browser you want to use.
>
> <sub>Source: [Browser Choice FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/ie/ff606439.aspx)</sub>

### References

- [Information about the Browser Choice update for system administrators who are in managed environments that are under a Volume Licensing program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019411/en-gb)